# Can you have an index pattern with a field with multiple field types?

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently I have an elasticsearch index that rolls over periodically. We have an index mapping applied to a certain index pattern. We want to update the field type of the index for subsequent indices that gets rolled over.

If we change the mapping of a field from a string type to number for new rolled over indices, what happens in the index pattern when refreshed?

Would the index pattern have the field as one type over the other?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one version of an index pattern at any given time. When you update it (i.e. change some mapping type), all the existing indices matching that index pattern remain unchanged. All future indices created out of that index pattern will get the modification (i.e. new field mapping type).

What you need to be aware is that you'll end up with (old) indices containing documents with a field having the old mapping type and (new) indices containing documents with a field having the new mapping type. Depending on the change you make, some of your queries running on old and new indices might not run correctly afterwards. Make sure that your queries still work with that mapping change.